# is the display inverted in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am building a game in which a ball is supposed to bounce off the edges of the screen but it seems that the display surface's rect is inverted because when the ball hits an edge, code prints out the other side (for example, when the ball hits the bottom edge, it prints 'top')

here is the code:

```
import pygame

def coll_side(obj1, obj2, is_obj1_rect, is_obj2_rect):
    if is_obj1_rect:
        rect1 = obj1
    else:
        rect1 = obj1.rect
    if is_obj2_rect:
        rect2 = obj2
    else:
        rect2 = obj2.rect

    tl = rect1.collidepoint(rect2.topleft)
    bl = rect1.collidepoint(rect2.bottomleft)
    tr = rect1.collidepoint(rect2.topright)
    br = rect1.collidepoint(rect2.bottomright)

    if tl and bl:
        side = 'left'
    elif tl and tr:
        side = 'top'
    elif br and tr:
        side = 'right'
    elif br and bl:
        side = 'bottom'
    elif tl:
        side = 'topleft'
    elif tr:
        side = 'topright'
    elif bl:
        side = 'bottomleft'
    elif br:
        side = 'bottomright'
    else:
        side = None    

    print side
    return side

class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.area = pygame.display.get_surface()
        self.rect = pygame.Rect((295, 455), (10,10))

    def update(self):
        if not self.area.contains(self.rect):
            side = coll_side(self.area.get_rect(), self.rect, True, True)
```

So, is there any problem with my code or pygame's display rect is inverted ?

Thanks

EDIT: Added link for screenshot

http://postimg.org/image/dcc3h50k9/

^in this scenario, the console outputs 'left'

Comment: Are you sure you don't have top and bottom confused? Typically (0, 0) is top-left whereas to most people it would make sense for (0, 0) to be bottom-left

Comment: `pygame.Rect((295, 455), (10,10))` did you mix up these 2 tuples? The Rect constructor->> `Rect((left, top), (width, height))`

Comment: @Tim i dont think so, i wanted a small square near the end of the screen of resolution 640x480

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Rect.collidepoint(x, y)` checks to see if the `x, y` coordinates you pass in are inside the `Rect` you're calling it on. So `screen.rect.collidepoint(ball.x, ball.y)` for example returns a bool after evaluating "Does this Rect *contain this exact point?*"

From the PyGame documentation:

> collidepoint()
>
> *test if a point is inside a rectangle*
>
> collidepoint(x,y) -> bool
>
> collidepoint((x,y)) -> bool
>
> Returns true if the given point is inside the rectangle. A point along
>   the right or bottom edge is not considered to be inside the rectangle.

In other words, I don't think this does what you want it to do in the first place. You're not establishing a bounds for the ball `rect` to stay in; you're just evaluating whether or not the rect has any of those four points inside of it.

Therefore, if you are using `screen.rect` as `rect1` and `ball.rect` as `rect2` and you are using a series of `if/elif/elif` as you are currently doing, then the first statement on your list - does the screen rect contain both the topleft and bottomleft corners of the ball rect - will typically evaluate to `True`, and it will not bother with the rest of the `elif`s.

If the ultimate goal of this function is to evaluate whether or not one Rect is entirely within another, you can use `obj.rect.contains(obj2.rect)`, which will return True or False depending on whether or not the second `Rect` is entirely inside the first.

Comment: yes, there's code that changes the direction of the ball when it hits the edge but i haven't included the code in the snippet as it is too big already

Comment: No, I'm not referring to movement, I'm saying that you're only checking whether or not rect1 has any of those four corners inside of it. `if tl and bl` doesn't establish a 'line' along the left side of the screen that the ball will notably cross; it just checks `(0, 0)` and `(0, screen_height)` to see if they exist inside `rect1`.

Comment: I got the problem,I wanted to check when edges of ball.rect had gone got out of screen.rect, the first statements in my fuction should have been `tl = not rect1.collidepoint(rect2.topleft)` Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

[The PyGame tutorial](http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/MoveIt.html) says:

> In pygame we always pass positions as an (X,Y) coordinate. This represents the number of pixels to the right, and the number of pixels down to place the image.

That's the standard coordinate system for 2D computer graphics.